# How can i know the average age of the users who downloaded my app on android & iOS?

Tags: android, ios, iphone, google-play

How can I know the average age of the users who downloaded my app on Android & iOS? I checked my app accounts but I didn't find any analytics related to user's ages any help?

Comment: For android, you can't, check out [available dimensions](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/139628?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&oco=1). You can get stuff like - Android OS version
- Device name
- Country
- Language
- Carrier
- Channel (how they launch your **instant app**).
- Which app version they downloaded

Comment: That ain't possible

Comment: Ask your users age inside you app ;)

Comment: can't get the ages from users apple id and gmail account?